# How to type a function parameter to be an instance of a decorated class

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I got a decorator that can be applied to any classes (e.g. entities from the consumer of my lib). 
The decorator just set some metadata using the reflect-metadata package.

Those decorated entities can be passed to my lib through a function parameter.
Is there a way to tell typescript that the parameter must be an instance of a class that uses the decorator?

```js
@MyDecorator()
class AnyClass {

}

function use(anInstanceDecoratedByMyDecorator: ?){
  // ...
}
```

So far, my best guess is set the parameter to `any`, do a runtime check and throw if the metadata is not set:

```js
function use(anInstanceDecoratedByMyDecorator: any){
  if (
    'object' !== typeof anInstance
    && 
    Reflect.hasMetdata(KEY, anInstanceDecoratedByMyDecorator)
  ) {
    throw new Error('Invalid');
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Nope not possible. Decorators do no change the type of the class in any way. You could use a function instead `const AnyClass = MyDecorator(class {})`, the return type of the function could add something to the class to mark it as decorated. I can provide a solution if you are intrested

Comment: relevant [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) which is [waiting for decorators in JS to be more finalized](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881#issuecomment-450938639)

Comment: Fair enough, that confirm what I thought, thank you both for your comment, that was helpful.